# How to modify currentUserStore in mobx-state-tree

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to wrap my head around mobx-state-tree and whipped up a simple currentUserStore to hold some data for a logged in user and allow login/logout:

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";
import { client } from '../../../helpers/client';

const User = types
  .model("User", {
    name: types.string,
    email: types.string,
    type: types.string,
    token: types.string,
    roles: types.array(types.string),
  })

export const CurrentUserStore = types
  .model("CurrentUserStore", {
    user: types.optional(types.maybeNull(User), () => null)
  })
  .actions((currentUserStore) => ({
    async login(login, password) {
      const result = await client.post(`auth`, {
        email: login,
        password,
      });


      const { name, email, type, token, roles } = result

      currentUserStore.user = User.create({ name, email, type, token, roles })
      localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    logout() {
      currentUserStore.user = null
      localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
    },
  }));
```

When calling the login function, I get the error `Cannot modify 'CurrentUserStore@/currentUserStore', the object is protected and can only be modified by using an action.`.  There's something I'm missing here, but not exactly sure why I shouldn't be able to do something like this after reading through example where the store is modified directly in an action like this.

Answer (score 0):

Once I moved the modification out of an async func, it worked.  Just changed to this:

```
async login(login, password) {
  const result = await client.post(`auth`, {
    email: login,
    password,
  });

  this.setUser(User.create(result))
  localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(result));
},
logout() {
  currentUserStore.user = null
  localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
},
setUser(user) {
  self.user = user
}
```